# Fatal Error XXX.pom:3:3: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed

Tags: java, gradle

I am using Gradle to build Java projects, when building the project in Intellj IDEA or build with command line, Gradle reports some *Fatal Error*s about dependencies. However, the build succeeds but I still wonder what's the cause and solution. I have searched Google and upgraded Gradle to latest but the error still remains.

Here is the error message:

[image]

```java
Welcome to Gradle 6.8!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Faster Kotlin DSL script compilation
 - Vendor selection for Java toolchains
 - Convenient execution of tasks in composite builds
 - Consistent dependency resolution

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
[Fatal Error] commons-text-1.9.pom:3:3: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
[Fatal Error] slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.pom:3:3: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
[Fatal Error] junit-4.11.pom:3:3: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
[Fatal Error] org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.24.0.pom:3:3: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 43s
```

Comment: Did you recompile with -Xlint:unchecked to get more details?

Comment: Yes, I recompile it and it reports 64 warnings and leads to a failed compilation, but it seems irrelevant with the pom XML, Fatal Errors are still reported.